# Label position of an Angular Material nested Stepper gets overwritten

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

Looking at a **nested Angular Material Stepper**, the label position in the child stepper (`labelPosition="end"`) **gets overwritten** by the label position in the parent stepper (`labelPosition="bottom"`), as in the following example:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper labelPosition="bottom" linear #stepper>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" [editable]="isEditable">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>ParentLabel</ng-template>
        <mat-horizontal-stepper labelPosition="end" linear #stepperChild>
            <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" [editable]="isEditable">
                <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
                    <ng-template matStepLabel>ChildLabel</ng-template>
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                        <input matInput
                          formControlName="firstCtrl"
                          placeholder="Last name, First name"
                          required
                        />
                    </mat-form-field>
                </form>
            </mat-step>
        </mat-horizontal-stepper>
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

[Here's a Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhqn1z?file=src/app/stepper-editable-example.html) showcasing the issue. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you dig around the Angular Material source code (currently `11.2`) a little, you can find out how the classes are applied internally depending of the `labelPosition`.

`material/stepper/stepper.ts`

```
'[class.mat-stepper-label-position-end]': 'labelPosition == "end"',
'[class.mat-stepper-label-position-bottom]': 'labelPosition == "bottom"',
```

Digging through the stylesheet (`material/stepper/stepper.scss`) you can see that `label-position-end` does not actually have any styles applied to it. `label-position-bottom` however has a few style properties, which are applied to **all its children**.

This might be a bug in Angular Material itself, as the styles are not scoped to accommodate nested steppers. It might also be that nested steppers are unintended.

Open an issue in `angular/components` to get in contact with the developers. Or create a PR.